# in adobe cs6 flash how to create a random movement

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How do I create a random movement animation in Adobe CS6 Flash?

Here is the code I used:

```
onClipEvent(enterFrame){
    this._alpha=Math.floor(100*Math.random());
    this._x=Math.floor(50*Math.random());
    this._y=Math.floor(50*Math.random());
}
```

It's not working in **action script 3**. I want to start my animation when I click the button, but it should be start in a different place.so how to do it?. my movie clip instance name is f1

Comment: It doesn't work in ActionScript 3 because it isn't ActionScript 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame)


    function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void 
    {
        f1.alpha = Math.floor(100*Math.random());
        f1.x = Math.floor(50*Math.random());
        f1.y = Math.floor(50*Math.random());
    }
```